# Display whatever is "under" a locked cell/row/column in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

In excel, you have the option to "lock" certain rows and/or columns so they scroll with the page (similar to `position: fixed;` in CSS).

What I want to do is have a certain cell, lets say A5, to display whatever value it's currently over. So, for example

[image]

Here, the row A is locked, so whenever we want to scroll down, we see this:

[image]

So, instead of seeing the values of the locked row, A in this case, I want to see B1:B6.

Of course, this is just a simplified example (which, needless to say, would be horribly pointless!).

(It should preferably be possible to do this with a formula, since my VB really isn't the best)

**EDIT:**

tl;dr: Do anyone know of any built-in function (or if you have constructed a formula) which enables me to show, in this case, the values of the cells that looks to be exactly underneath the locked row/column/cell?

Basically, whenever the user scrolls the page (and therefore the view, *except for the locked row*, changes) the locked row/column/cell should show (or contain, doesn't really matter) the values of the cell that is underneath it

(I have a document where a locked row (lets call it 'A') contains a couple of headings, but further down the document there is even more headings. I want 'A' to change to the values of the last encountered headings in the document whenever the user scrolls and a heading comes under A (read: whenever A hides a (sub-)heading).)

Comment: Are your 1-6 and A-H marks meant to be the Row and Column labels you always see in Excel? Perhaps a more specific example would make more sense?

Comment: My fault, sorry. I missed that I cut the picture at the wrong place, see the changes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going to need to use VBA to get the current scroll position. See Stack Overflow [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700203/how-do-i-get-the-scroll-position-from-microsoft-excel).

You cannot use a formula to read the state of the User interface. You will need to use VBA for this.